# Unable to start debugging in PyCharm 2023.2

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

OS Linux: Solus 4.4

I'm trying to debug a program that interacts with the Dialog library. But when I start debugging I get an exception "Error opening terminal: unknown."

As I understand it, PyCharm cannot output data generated by the Dialog library to the console. How can I debug this process? Or is it possible to use a third-party terminal somehow?

```
d = Dialog(dialog="dialog")
code = d.yesno("Test", title="Test", height=5, width=64, yes_label=_("One"), no_label=_("Two"))
```

An error occurs on the "yesno" call line, which I cited above.

If I run script separately in the terminal, then everything is fine

[image]

Debugging in vscode works

Comment: may need more details about it

Comment: @Jiu_Zou Added a description to the question

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a project configuration and enable the "Emulate terminal in output console" option in the "Modify options" drop-down menu

[image]